# How to make Vertical TabLayout in Android

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-tablayout

Hi i am trying to make vertical tab layout.tried using rotate view but it does not help its not recalculate views height and view.any help will be appreciated to achieve below result.

[image]

Comment: I don't think there is an easy way to do this using the existing controls, and this leads me to think you should rethink your design.

Why would you want to do that?  It is a very strange UI paradigm (I have NEVER seen this before in ANY app).

Comment: Have a look at some of the links in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22385063/android-layout-with-vertical-tabs-design-like-hello-sms-app

Comment: @Booger this image is just for making things easy to explain. Actually I tried to make this concept UI. Where vertical tabs and items scroll horizontal. https://dribbble.com/shots/6528470-Plant-shop-app-concept . Thanks for taking time out to answer this . I m curious to make this design as i not found anything related to tabs on internet.

Comment: I will try that approach too @Nikos thanks for suggestions

Answer (score 2):

This might help you.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:rotation="-90"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/CDTabLayoutTextAppearance"
        app:tabInlineLabel="true"
        app:tabIconTint="@color/tab_tint_color_selector"
        app:tabIndicatorFullWidth="false"
        app:tabIndicator="@drawable/ic_community_tab_selected"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorColoringDesk"
        android:background="@color/white" >

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tabItemContacts"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Contacts" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tabItemChat"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Chat" />

    </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Use TabLayout with ViewPager2.

[image: Rotate your FrameLayout]

Answer (score 1):

I made vertical tabLayout using following code. You can also try it:-

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:rotation="-90"
    android:transformPivotX="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/tab_width"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-24dp">
    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:layout_width="@dimen/tab_width"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/black"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/light_grey"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="2dp"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white"
        app:tabPaddingBottom="-10dp">
        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ABC"/>
        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="XYZ"/>
    </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Code For VerticalTabLayout!
I am using Jetpack Compose. For the vertical Tab, I am using Modifier.onGloballyPositioned to calculate the Item Height and indicator Height. And I am Using a Vertical-Scroll Column For Item List.

[image]

```
@Composable
fun MDVerticalTabLayout(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    bottomPaddingDp: Dp = 0.dp,
    list: SnapshotStateList<CategoryItem>,
    gradientFirstColor: Color,
    gradientSecondColor: Color,
    indicatorColor: Color,
    indicatorHeightType: IndicatorHeightType = IndicatorHeightType.FIXED,
    indicatorHeight: Dp = 58.dp,
    textStyle: TextStyle = TextStyle.Default,
    onItemClick: (CategoryItem) -> Unit,
) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val globalOffsetYPosition = rememberSaveable {
        mutableIntStateOf(0)
    }
    val globalHeight = rememberSaveable {
        mutableIntStateOf(0)
    }

    val selectedPosition = rememberSaveable {
        mutableIntStateOf(0)
    }

    val movementThreshHold = remember {
        100
    }

    val offsetYPosition = rememberSaveable {
        mutableIntStateOf(0)
    }

    val heightOfItem = rememberSaveable {
        mutableIntStateOf(0)
    }
    val listState = rememberScrollState()
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val map = remember {
        hashMapOf<Int, Int>()
    }

    val durationMillis = rememberSaveable {
        mutableStateOf(0)
    }

    // Define the animation spec
    val animationSpec by remember {
        derivedStateOf {
            tween<Offset>(
                durationMillis = durationMillis.value,
                easing = FastOutSlowInEasing,
            )
        }
    }

    val animationSpecForScroll by remember {
        derivedStateOf {
            tween<Float>(
                durationMillis = 600,
                easing = FastOutSlowInEasing,
            )
        }
    }

    // Create an animated offset
    val animatedOffset by animateOffsetAsState(
        targetValue = Offset(x = 0F, y = offsetYPosition.value.toFloat()),
        animationSpec = animationSpec,
        label = "",
    )

    val indicatorHeight by remember {
        derivedStateOf {
            when (indicatorHeightType) {
                IndicatorHeightType.FIXED -> {
                    indicatorHeight
                }
                IndicatorHeightType.FILL -> {
                    getDp(context, heightOfItem.intValue)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Scaffold(
        modifier = modifier
            .background(Color.White)
            .fillMaxHeight()
            .width(78.dp)
            .onGloballyPositioned {
                globalOffsetYPosition.value = it.positionInRoot().y.toInt()
                globalHeight.value = it.size.height
            },
        content = { paddingValues ->
            Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight().padding(paddingValues), elevation = 10.dp) {
                Box(
                    contentAlignment = Alignment.TopEnd,
                ) {
                    Column(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .verticalScroll(listState)
                            .width(78.dp),
                    ) {
                        list.forEachIndexed { position, item ->
                            map[position] = 0
                            var height: Int = 0

                            ItemSubCategory(
                                item = item,
                                onChecked = selectedPosition.value == position,
                                gradientFirstColor = gradientFirstColor,
                                gradientSecondColor = gradientSecondColor,
                                textStyle = textStyle,
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .onGloballyPositioned {
                                        map[position] = it.positionInRoot().y.toInt()
                                        height = it.size.height
                                        if (selectedPosition.value == position) {
                                            height = it.size.height
                                            offsetYPosition.value =
                                                it.positionInRoot().y.toInt() - globalOffsetYPosition.value
                                            heightOfItem.value = height
                                        }
                                    }
                                    .fillMaxWidth(),
                            ) {
                                durationMillis.value = 600
                                offsetYPosition.intValue = map[position] ?: (0 - globalOffsetYPosition.intValue)
                                selectedPosition.intValue = position
                                heightOfItem.intValue = height
                                coroutineScope.launch {
                                    if (offsetYPosition.intValue <= height + movementThreshHold) {
                                        listState.animateScrollTo(animationSpec = animationSpecForScroll, value = listState.value - height / 2 - movementThreshHold)
                                    } else if (offsetYPosition.intValue >= globalHeight.intValue - height / 2 - movementThreshHold) {
                                        listState.animateScrollTo(animationSpec = animationSpecForScroll, value = (listState.value + height / 2 + movementThreshHold))
                                    }
                                    delay(600)
                                    durationMillis.value = 0
                                }
                                onItemClick(item)
                            }
                            if (position == list.size - 1) {
                                Spacer(
                                    modifier = Modifier
                                        .padding(bottom = bottomPaddingDp)
                                        .fillMaxWidth()
                                        .background(Color.White),
                                )
                            } else {
                                Spacer(
                                    modifier = Modifier
                                        .fillMaxWidth()
                                        .background(Color.White),
                                )
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    Box(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .offset(
                                x = getDp(context, animatedOffset.x.toInt()),
                                y = getDp(context, animatedOffset.y.toInt()),
                            )
                            .padding(top = 24.dp)
                            .width(3.dp)
                            .height(indicatorHeight)
                            .background(
                                color = indicatorColor,
                                shape = RoundedCornerShape(2.dp),
                            ),

                    )
                }
            }
        },
    )
}


fun getDp(context: Context, offset: Int): Dp {
    val resources = context.resources
    val metrics = resources.displayMetrics
    val dpValue = offset / (metrics.densityDpi.toFloat() / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT)
    return dpValue.dp
}

enum class IndicatorHeightType {
    FILL,
    FIXED,
}
```

Comment: I think OP want vertical writing, not vertical scroll