# How to display the Tabs from the TabLayout one above the other on left side of the screen in android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-tablayout

So, I am trying to display three Tabs [Easy, Medium, Hard] in TabLayout and I want these Tabs to get displayed one above the other. Currently I am getting result like this [image]

So, as you can see, these tabs are one next to other instead of one below the other.Following is code of my XML file

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="scrollable" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:background="@drawable/flash_tablebar"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/back_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_back" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/relativeFlashcard"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/back_icon"
            >
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:text="Flashcards"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textColor="#FFF" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/subtext_flash"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_below="@id/title_text"
                android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                android:text="Pick a set to practice"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textColor="#FFF" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
        <!-- ViewPager -->
        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:contentDescription="" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerViewFlashcards"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="70dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:scrollbars="vertical">
        </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And following is the code of my Fragment class

```
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
import com.example.visuallithuanian.R
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter
import com.example.visuallithuanian.EasyFragment
import com.example.visuallithuanian.HardFragment
import com.example.visuallithuanian.MediumFragment
import dagger.hilt.android.AndroidEntryPoint


@AndroidEntryPoint
class FlashCards : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var tabLayout: TabLayout
    private lateinit var viewPager: ViewPager

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_flash_cards,
container, false)

        // Initialize views
        tabLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.tabLayout)
        viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager)

        // Set up the ViewPager and TabLayout
        val adapter = FlashCardsPagerAdapter(childFragmentManager)
        viewPager.adapter = adapter
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)

        return view
    }

    private inner class FlashCardsPagerAdapter(fm: FragmentManager) :
FragmentPagerAdapter(fm) {

        override fun getCount(): Int {
            return 3 // Number of tabs (Easy, Medium, Hard)
        }

        override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
            return when (position) {
                0 -> EasyFragment()
                1 -> MediumFragment()
                2 -> HardFragment()
                else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Invalid position")
            }
        }

        override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence? {
            return when (position) {
                0 -> "Easy"
                1 -> "Medium"
                2 -> "Hard"
                else -> null
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, I just want these Tabs to be one above the other like first Easy , then medium and then Hard so I can traverse the respective Fragments. I want my Tabs to look like this [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since API11, we can rotate views by calling [`setRotation()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setRotation(float)) or by setting the XML attribute `android:rotation`. You could try to attach this attribute to the views to achieve the desired result. To rotate a view by 90 degress clockwise, just set `android:rotation="90"`.

Use below layout to get the idea. Note that I am not able to test it right now, but this could provide you some direction. We first rotate the whole Tablayout cw, and then we rotate back the single TabItems.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:rotation="90"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
        app:tabInlineLabel="true"
        app:tabIndicatorFullWidth="false"
        android:background="@color/white" >

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tabItemEasy"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:rotation="-90"
            android:text="Easy" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tabItemMedium"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:rotation="-90"
            android:text="Medium" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tabItemHard"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:rotation="-90"
            android:text="Hard" />

    </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

See also [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58414671/how-to-make-vertical-tablayout-in-android-studio) for reference.

Please however note that this design approach in general does not conform to the [Google Material Design Guidelines](https://m3.material.io/), so you might want to overthink if there are alternatives more suitable.

Comment: This XML layout's fragment would be my EASY Fragment, right ?

Comment: @TejasKhartude No, this XML contains the TabLayout, so it should be in a parent layout file. In your case, I think this XML should go into fragment_flash_cards.xml. Just insert it instead of your current TabLayout.

Comment: Yes, this is fragment flashcards.xml. so what I was thinking was I should make this as my default Easy fragment, and then create two more fragments medium and Hard , so I can traverse on what I want. do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: @TejasKhartude If you want to use one Fragment each instead of just changing Fragments with RecyclerView, have a look at FragmentTransactions:
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentTransaction.html

Comment: I do have recyclerview in this fragment, what but the contents of flashcards will be different. Are you saying I can use just this one fragment and just call the list of flashcards using when as per the position of the Tab?

Comment: What my understanding of a suitable approach is: 
1) You link together the TabLayout and the ViewPager
2) You add three Fragments (easy, medium, hard) to the ViewPager
3) Each Fragment just contains a List of cards
4) Now when you select a TabItem, the ViewPager will show the respective Fragment.

Comment: Okay, agreed. so my question, when i open this screen, what content will I see? Is this going to be my Easy Fragment by default?

Comment: You can define in ViewPager or in the TabLayout which page should be shown first. So you can define which Fragment is going to be the default initial Fragment.

Comment: Default intial Fragment will be one of the three , right? I am planning to display this fragment for Easy and create two more Fragments for Medium and hard respectively.

Comment: Yes, I think by default the ViewPager displays its first page.